# Distribution of a uniform random variable with random endpoint

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $Y \sim U[0,k]$, where $0 < k < \infty$ and $U$ is a continuous uniform distribution. Now let $X \sim U[0, Y]$. What is the distribution of $X$? Is it possible to express in terms of some well-known distribution?

Comment: Are you sure $k$ is not bounded from above? You may have some convergence problems.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the question to reflect this.

Comment: I'd write "$X\mid Y\sim U(0,Y)$".  ($X\mid Y$, not to be confused with $X|Y$, but that's just a typographical point.)

Comment: The change in the posting from $k>0$ to $0<k<\infty$ is really no change at all.  But I don't see how "convergence problems" result from $k$ being arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<x<k$,
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(X\le x) & = \mathbb E(\Pr(X\le x \mid Y)) \\[12pt]
& = \mathbb E \left.\begin{cases}
\dfrac x Y & \text{if }Y>x \\[8pt] 1 & \text{if }Y<x
\end{cases}\right\} = 1\Pr(Y<x) + \mathbb E\left(\frac x Y\mid Y>x\right)\Pr(Y>x) \\[10pt]
& = \frac x k + \frac{k-x}{k}\int_x^k \frac x y \, \frac{dy}{k-x} \\[10pt]
& = \frac x k + \frac{x}{k} \int_x^k \frac{dy}{y} = \frac x k\left(1 + \log_e \frac k x \right).
\end{align}
$$

The density is therefore the derivative of that:
$$
\frac{-1}{k}\log_e \frac x k \text{ for }0<x<k\text{ (and $0$ for }x<0\text{ or }x>k).
$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Do you by any chance know a reference where I can learn more about these kinds of distributions, where the parameters of the distributions themselves are random?

Comment: You might search for "hierarchical models".